# JavaScript and security/anonymity

Tags: security, javascript

From what I've read, JavaScript is a security risk. However, many sites don't work without it. If I deactivate JavaScript, but also define exceptions for sites that I regularly use, would it be safe?

Comment: Javascript itself isn't insecure, it's just very easy to make something that isn't safe with it. What kind of security risks *specifically* are you afraid of?

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a very good time on the internet if you disable JavaScript and it really isn't that big of a risk. The bigger risk is the browser you are using.

If you really want to lock down JavaScript then try using a tool like https://noscript.net/

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but I can find a similar extension myself. Thank you very much!